# Salty water occasionally when showering

Tags: water, water-softener

I've noticed that about once every 2 weeks, I'll get a sudden rush of salt water. It tastes salty and smells metallic. It goes away after a couple minutes.

Usually when showering but I'm sure that is just because of the large amount of water being used. It has happened just through the sink as well.

I've checked the water softener tank for salt bridges, and didn't find any.

Is this just a normal occurrence with a water softener, or should I get it looked at?

Comment: It sounds like the regeneration cycle is not fully flushing , can you change the time of day when in regen so it is not running during the time of usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgot to update. The water conditioning company said it's not because of the regeneration time.

They said that it's a fairly common issue where drain and/or control valves are dirty and either need to be cleaned or replaced. In my case they replaced both types of valves.

They also advised me to run cold water (not hot) until the saltiness passed. That way the salty water wouldn't get in the hot water tank.

Answer (score 0):

If your tap water has a salty aftertaste, it is likely caused by either a high concentration of chloride ions and/or sulfates in your water supply. This is due to industrial waste, irrigation drainage or seawater entering local reservoirs.
Although in most instances your water will be safe to drink, it is important to get your water tested as contaminants can cause damage to pipes in your home.
If you have well water and are using a softener you may have to adjust your setting or purchase a new softener.
Either way have your water tested. Most places will do this free of charge.

Comment: Hm, wouldn't that be if the water *always* tastes that way? In my case it is only salty < 1% of the time